Is it possible to run a windows application console within Python GUI
I'm new to python and would like to know if there is a possible way to integrate another console application into python GUI like Tkinter or any other libraries.
eg.
Entry(pathToFile\win.exe).pack()
or
Label(pathToFile\win.exe).pack()
I found ways to open the file using os modules.
For eg.
os.startfile(" path to file/win.exe)
But they open the application in separate window.
I'm looking for a wat to have the console of the win application attached to the python GUI in one of the grid locations.
Please let me know if there is a way for this problem or a dead end.

There isn't a way built-in to tkinter but some stuff like xterm and vlc (I think) have options to put their respective windows inside a tk.Frame using a command line argument. For example for xteem there is a -into argument and you can pass in the result from winfo_id() like this

if you run console application (without GUI) then you may try to run it with subprocess.run() or subprocess.popen() and it allows to catch text from other aplication (stdout, stdin) and you may display it in tkinter.Text. And I think someone created module tkconsole which probobaly may use this method.

I found using Google: python - How to add a console to a tkinter window - Stack Overflow

I found using Google: Python interpreter console tkinter widget

I found using Google: tkterminal · PyPI

the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example
